# Configuring Jenkins CI Job and FreeFileSync Batch Using Windows Batch Command

Tags: windows, jenkins, command-line, cmd, continuous-integration

I have just setup **Jenkins CI** as my build server but I have an issue with correctly configuring **FreeFileSync** batch file and the command that calls the  batch file used for deploying the application after building it.

```
call Path\deploy.ffs_batch
```

The build console displays success if `deploy.ffs_batch` execution was successful. But in the case of where the `deploy.ffs_batch` settings was wrong for example *wrong path as destination*, the build never stops and console log spinner on Hudson keeps spinning without stopping and without giving any information.

What I have tried is adding this command below the one above to the Windows batch command:

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit %errorlevel%
```

But build still not happy (spinner keeps spinning).

However, when I check the log folder for FreeFileSync batch file, I see this:

> [03:52:46 PM] Info: Starting comparison 
>   [03:52:46 PM] Error: Cannot find the following folders:
>                        D:\Deploy\1\Dev
>                        You can ignore this error to consider each folder as empty. The folders then will be created automatically during
>   synchronization.  
>   [03:52:46 PM] Error: Synchronization stopped

I do understand the error and I can fix it. But I really do not want to always look in the log folder for answers when this occurs. So my question is how can I output the FreeFileSync error on Hudson console log and also abort the build using Windows batch command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that I was missing one vital step when an error occurred and that is stopping the synchronization when an error occurs to prevent hudson job build from running endlessly.

[image: FreeFileSync Batch Job]

After setting this to stop, I update my batch command to:

```
cd "Path\FreeFileSync\" 
FreeFileSync.exe "Path\deploy.ffs_batch"
echo.
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
echo ##### Results :
echo ===============================================================================
echo.
echo.
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir "Path\logs\" /od /b') do set recent=%%x
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto SYNCSUCCESS
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto SYNCWARNINGS
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 2 goto SYNCERRORS
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 3 goto SYNCABORTED
goto SYNCFAIL
:SYNCFAIL
echo ##### FreeFileSync failed.
type "path\logs\%recent%"
exit 2
:SYNCSUCCESS
echo ##### FreeFileSync completed successfully!
exit 0
:SYNCWARNINGS
echo ##### FreeFileSync completed, but with warnings.
type "path\logs\%recent%"
exit 1
:SYNCERRORS
echo ##### FreeFileSync completed, but with warnings.
type "path\logs\%recent%"
exit 2
:SYNCABORTED
echo ##### FreeFileSync aborted.
type "path\logs\%recent%"
exit 3
```

**Please note:** Run minimized checkbox needs to be checked also to avoid the job from running continously.
The job runs and stops when there is an error.